# Burn [slow-load]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Can we burn [slow-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow-load) or synonym it to [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance)? It seems to be related [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow) or [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance).

Answer (score 7):

[slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow) is actually a synonym of [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance), so [slow-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow-load) would be merged into [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) if anything.

Looking into [slow-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow-load), the tag only has 82 questions and means about the same thing as [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow).  It is always used to mean something that loads slowly (i.e. is [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow) or has poor [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance)).  Thus, it should definitely be removed.

I have gone and proposed [slow-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slow-load) as a synonym for [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance).  I encourage those with sufficient scores to vote on my proposal and help complete the merge.

Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance/synonyms